# Quotient of Poincare dodecahedral space-example of spherical orbifold

Tags: orbifolds

Let $\mathcal{O}$ the orbifold with underlying space $S^3$ and singular locus the trefoil knot with local groups of order five. Then how can we see that it is the quotient space of the Poincare dodecahedral space by a cyclic orthogonal action of order five?